# Is Apache POI supports replacing merge fields in docx?

Tags: apache-poi, ms-office, docx, mergefield

To replace ms word merge-fields with values with apache-poi both in paragraphs and tables with multiple columns.

As docx4j provides the function to replace merge-fields, is there any equivalent function by apache poi. Since I am using some custom tags in Docx file, reading the file in docx4j is ignoring custom tags(xml format "w:xyz").

Input Template

```
Name «name»

Table :   (Need to add n- number of records to the template)  
ID      Name
«id»    «name»
```

Output expected :

```
Name:  Stack

    ID  Name
    1   Java
    2   Apache
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't.
However there is an apache library for it, called [Freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/).
 It is a template engine and fully supports what are you looking for.